# iOS application not responsive after "Home button" pressed and resumed

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am experiencing some strange behavior of the iOS application I am developing.

E.G.:

When I press the home button of the device the app closes. When I resume the app from "Recent open application" the application becomes not responsive.

Furthermore, when I "force close" the application and open it again, it is working normal until the moment I press the "Home button" again.

Here is some application characteristics:

- Developed using `Swift`
- Developed on `Xcode 9.4`
- I have not included any specific libraries
- Using `GoogleMaps API`for part of the application

Any ideas why this problem occurs?

UPDATE:

Here is my `AppDelegate.swift` file/class:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("<API KEY>")
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
}
```

Comment: are you doing something in the appdelegate

Comment: please check on another device if same problem persists

Comment: @sanjaykmwt Yes it gives the same problem on another device. The only thing i added in the AppDelegate class is the GoogleMaps functionality.

Comment: @DimitarGeorgiev can you update your question with what you have done on AppDelegate class

Comment: @PranavanSp I just updated my question.

Comment: Did you look into your code for `applicationWillEnterForeground` & `applicationDidEnterBackground `notifications and see if you're doing something there?

Comment: @PranavanSp Both methods are empty

Comment: @DimitarGeorgiev google map keep tracking user location even if app is closed below iOS 11. When app is closed and not running in background then location never track in iOS 11. try to check google map background running